# Dumping Fiddler sessions automatically

Tags: fiddler

I need to do some data analysis on xml data coming in http responses. Is there a way to set fiddler dump these responses automatically on disk?
(I have filtered the responses, dumping the sessions works too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a situation like this one I make a simple edit to the `OnBeforeResponse` function in the Fiddler rules.  Choose `Rules | Customize Rules` and then add something similar to this::

```
if (oSession.url.Contains(".xml")) {
    var directory: String = "C:\\Temp\\XML";
    var path: String = System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, Guid.NewGuid() + ".xml");
      oSession.SaveResponseBody(path);
}
```

The line that I am using to 'filter' the requests may not be appropriate for your situation -- you should attempt to repeat the filter condition that you used in the Fiddler UI.\

Hope that helps.

Comment: Note that you may want to call oSession.utilDecodeResponse() first, in the event that your XML was gzip'd or chunked.